# Using select to detect keyboard input

Tags: c, select

I am writing a simple server using select to monitor multiple sickets.

Here's my code:

```
while (1) { /* Main server loop - forever */
    build_select_list();
    timeout.tv_sec = 1;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    readsocks = select(maxSock+1, &socks, (fd_set *) 0, (fd_set *) 0, &timeout);

    if (readsocks < 0) {
        perror("select");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (readsocks == 0) {
        printf(".");
        fflush(stdout);
    } else
        read_socks();
}
```

I know select detecs changes in the sockets it is monitoring and "report" about it. Can I detect a keyboard input from the user (for commands like exit) by using select? If not, how do I do this?

Comment: This looks a lot more like `C` than `C++` to me. So much so that I am going to retag it. If you're really writing `C++` feel free to rollback.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780051/linux-c-select-piping-echo-to-input-works-but-reading-from-keyboard-doesnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `STDIN_FILENO` (from unistd.h), or use `fileno(stdin)` (from stdio.h), to get the file descriptor of the console input. Add that to your 'read' fdset, and `select` will "do the right thing", indicating when there's console input available. From there, just read from it like any other file descriptor.